# Space out part of the pie chart in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I space out pie of the chart in nvd3 / d3?

I would like to use pie chart as per example pie chart from http://nvd3.com/livecode/#codemirrorNav

Any help really appriciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sometimes a thick white stroke on each slice does OK (in fact, that's how they do it on the page you linked to). The problem is that tiny slices will sometimes get covered by the stroke.

```
.slice {
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 3;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, can't believe I have missed it. Thanks a lot Trevor.

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this transparently (in case the chart sits on a background...) ?

Comment: Try `stroke-opacity: 0`.

Comment: I had to select the slice borders like this: `.nv-slice path { ... }`